# Webpack 5.47.1 : Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using React Application. Below is my Webpack Configuration file for `5.47.1`.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

process.noDeprecation = true;

module.exports = (options) => ({
  entry: options.entry,
  output: Object.assign({ // Compile into js/build.js
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
    publicPath: '/',
  }, options.output), // Merge with env dependent settings
  module: {
    mode: 'development',
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: options.babelQuery,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              progressive: true,
              optimizationLevel: 7,
              interlaced: false,
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: options.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      // make fetch available
      fetch: 'exports-loader?self.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
    }),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV' : JSON.stringify('development'),
    }),
    // new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  ]),
  resolve: {
    modules: ['app', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.jsx',
      '.react.js',
    ],
    mainFields: [
      'browser',
      'jsnext:main',
      'main',
    ],
  },
  devtool: options.devtool,
  target: 'web', // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
  performance: options.performance || {},
});
```

I have updated `mode`. Could not figure out the config issues here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mode` should be in the root object and not in the module object:

```js
module.exports = (options) => ({
    mode: 'development',
    entry: options.entry,
    output: Object.assign({ // Compile into js/build.js
        path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
        publicPath: '/',
    }, options.output), // Merge with env dependent settings
    module: {

        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: options.babelQuery,
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: /node_modules/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: 'file-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    'file-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        options: {
                            progressive: true,
                            optimizationLevel: 7,
                            interlaced: false,
                            pngquant: {
                                quality: '65-90',
                                speed: 4,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                use: 'json-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: 10000,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: options.plugins.concat([
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            // make fetch available
            fetch: 'exports-loader?self.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
        }),

        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
        }),
        // new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    ]),
    resolve: {
        modules: ['app', 'node_modules'],
        extensions: [
            '.js',
            '.jsx',
            '.react.js',
        ],
        mainFields: [
            'browser',
            'jsnext:main',
            'main',
        ],
    },
    devtool: options.devtool,
    target: 'web', // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
    performance: options.performance || {},
});
```

Comment: Thanks this issue is resolved. But when i make the above changes, i am getting `TypeError: compiler.plugin is not a function` error. Do you know about it?

Comment: This error sometimes arises when you use webpack 4 plugins with webpack 5, maybe try updating some stuff. You can also try to remove the plugins to figure out which one is causing problems...